# the profile image isnt displaying

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

```php
**this is the controller function for login** 

function login_user()
{
  if(isset($_POST['login']))
  {
    $data = $this->Model_students->existentUserEmail();

    if(!empty($data))
    {
      foreach ($data as $key => $value) :
        $user_id = $value->id;
        $firstname = $value->firstname;
        $lastname = $value->lastname;
        $grade = $value->grade;
        $email = $value->email;
        $images = json_decode($value->userfile);
      endforeach;

      $user_info = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'firstname' => $firstname,
        'lastname' => $lastname,
        'grade' => $grade,
        'email' => $email,
        'images' => $images,
        'is_logged_in' => TRUE
      );

      $data5=$this->session->set_userdata($user_info);
      var_dump($data5);
      redirect('Students/homepage');
    }
    else
    {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error! Invalid username or password');
      redirect('Students/login_user');
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $this->load->view('signup');
  }
}
```

the image placeholder in the view looks like this;

```
<a href=""> <img class ="img-circle" src="<?=base_url();?>uploads/users/<?=$this->session->userdata('images');?>" width="250" height="auto"></a>
```

now what im facing a challenge in is that the image doesn't display on the web page, this **uploads/users/** represents the folder where user details are stored after signing up.

Comment: what is your `var_dump($data5);` spitting out? Specially regarding to `'images'`

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't set the base url properly, then open the `application/config/config.php` file and set your base URL properly.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/path_to_ci_folder';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your application/config/config.php file and set your base URL if not set.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_folder_name/';
```

Also it seems your view needs correction.

```
<a href=""> <img class ="img-circle" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/users/<?php $this->session->userdata('images'); ?>" width="250" height="auto"></a>
```

Your session variable must contain filename with extension.

```
$this->session->userdata('images')
```

If the rest path of the file in src is correct your picture will show to you.

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/alternative_php.html